# Type annotation needed when use byteorder with vector

Tags: rust

I need to build a packet to send to the server. I use `byteorder` crate for this. One of my field contains `usize` data, so I use typecasting to convert it to the i16:

```
use byteorder::WriteBytesExt;

fn main () {
    let login = "test";
    let packet_length = 30 + (login.len() as i16);
    let mut packet = Vec::new();
    packet.write_u8(0x00);
    packet.write_i16(packet_length);
    packet.append(&mut Vec::from(String::from("game name ").as_bytes_mut()));
    // ... rest code
}
```

But I got an error:

```
packet.write_i16(packet_length);
 |     ^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the associated function `write_i16`
```

This is playground to reproduce.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1e5dd29816a128f7561e06f7c825864d

I am confused where I should to add type annotation here, could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the **endianness**, either [`BigEndian`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/latest/byteorder/enum.BigEndian.html) or [`LittleEndian`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/latest/byteorder/enum.LittleEndian.html):

```rust
packet.write_i16::<BigEndian>(packet_length);
```

or

```rust
BigEndian::write_u32(&mut packet, packet_lentgth);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d71e6639b9e4fe57e5b0b1f6a6c40392)